# How do I build a C Python Extension for Windows using Cygwin64?

Tags: python, c, windows, cygwin

To preface: my code works as I expect when compiling and running on Linux. However, this library needs to be compiled for use on a Windows machine. I looked in to a couple different options, and decided that using Cygwin to compile for Windows seemed to be the correct choice. I'm using a setup.py file with the distutils.core library and compiling using `python setup.py install`. When compiling on Windows in Cygwin, it fails to find `pthread.h`, `arpa/inet.h`, `netinet/in.h`, and `sys/socket.h`. I was under the impression that Cygwin came prepackaged with these headers, which is why I chose to use it. The alternative to Cygwin is putting preprocessor commands everywhere and using Windows specific libraries such as `winsock2.h`, which I want to avoid if at all possible. Is it possible to compile for Windows using Cygwin? If so, what have I done wrong to cause Cygwin to not recognize these headers?

Comment: What library are you trying to compile? Have you looked to see if it's available from [Christoph Gohlke's collection](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) of Python libraries for Windows?

Comment: @MattDMo I have built my own extension, and I'm attempting to compile that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the proper headers

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/include/pthread.h
Found 9 matches for usr/include/pthread.h
cygwin-devel-3.0.7-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
..
cygwin-devel-3.1.6-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
...
```

so install the `cygwin-devel` package

To check all the shared libraries needed by the built dll, you can use cygcheck

```
$ cygcheck /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/FlowControl.cpython-38-x86_64-cygwin.dll
D:\cygwin64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.cpython-38-x86_64-cygwin.
dll
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
  D:\cygwin64\bin\libpython3.8.dll
    D:\cygwin64\bin\cygintl-8.dll
      D:\cygwin64\bin\cygiconv-2.dll
    D:\cygwin64\bin\cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
```

As was built with Cygwin Python, you need also to transfer the cygwin python...

Comment: This solved the question! To make sure I had all the packages I needed, I installed everything from the devel section of the Cygwin package manager. I've ran into another wall regarding the .dll that got built. Do you know how I can distribute this to a different machine (outside of Cygwin) or must this .dll run within a Cygwin environment?

Comment: you must have a lot of cygwin dlls installed . `cygcheck ./your_program.exe` will give you a hint.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what .exe you're referring to. I ran ```python3 setup.py build``` which created a build folder and created <my_library>.cpython-36m-x86_64-cygwin.dll. I've found that to distribute it, I need to also have the cygwin1.dll file, which I've found. I'm not sure what to do with them on the machine that didn't compile the code.

Comment: @Zenith2198 added info on how to identify the dll dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Most important, I think, is to follow the instructions in the Python help or on the Python doc web site for "Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter" for the version you are building the extension for. For windows, the build instructions identify the build environment used to create the binary package that you download from python.org, usually something like VS2013 or VS2017. (As an aside, I think the Community editions have everything you need, and I don't think you actually have to use the Visual Studio GUI when you build using nmake from the CMD.EXE terminal.)

To build in Cygwin for use in a Windows version of Python, you may need to install and then use the x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc, etc., cygwin packages to cross-compile non-cygwin (i.e. pure windows) executables and DLLs from Cygwin.

Binary extensions must be built using the source tree for a specific Python major.minor version, and bitness. For windows, you will need to build multiple versions of the extension, one for each major.minor, bitness version of Python that will import it, e.g. 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 32-bit, 64-bit. The extension code may not require changes between versions, but it still needs to be compiled with the right compiler and linked against exactly the same shared libraries (in this case .DLL files) as used by the Python executable. For instance, it must use exactly the same version of Microsoft's C run time library DLL as the Python executable does. This is a bit more sensitive and restrictive than on Linux, where you can rebuild the python executable and your extension with the same toolchain from your distro more easily.

Comment: I won't have to worry about targeting many different build types, as the final goal of this is to just have a C Python Extension importable on a singular target Windows machine. When I try compiling after running ```export CC=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc``` I get an import error for ```<sys/select.h>``` thrown from ```/usr/include/pythonX.Y/pyport.h```. When compiling using the default GCC, it throws no errors and creates a DLL. I'm just not sure where to put this DLL on the target Windows machine or what else I need to include/do with it.

Comment: I'd have to check the python packaging doc. I think you may have to build a wheel containing the extension DLL. Then you use pip to install the package on the target machine.

Comment: I've managed to build a wheel, and I included cygwin1.dll and libpython3.8.dll as dependencies in the package_data section of setup.py. However, when importing it gives me an error "Could not find module 'path\to\site-packages\<library>\<library>.cpython-38-x86_64-cygwin.dll' (or one of its dependencies)." I can confirm the .dll is in that location, so I imagine I'm missing a dependency. How do I figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think you want to include cygwin1.dll in your wheel, nor should you have to have libpython3.8.dll in the wheel. The latter is the python from Cygwin. You want to dynamically link to the equivalent file in the windows python install tree. I'm on mobile now so you will need to check if it is beside the python.exe or in the lib directory beside the exe. It might be called python.dll or python3.8.dll. Again, I suggest you use the mingw GCC in Cygwin, or switch to using a mingw64 system.